# MySQL left Join taking too much time

Tags: mysql, database

I am trying to understand why this mysql statement is taking so long to load.. basically i have 3 tables, each have column VIN as unique and each VIN exist in all the 3

```
SELECT * FROM vehicle_information i 
 LEFT JOIN vehicle_extra e on i.vin = e.vin 
LEFT JOIN Images im on i.vin = im.vin
```

I have about 4000 vins that should populate and its taking about 10 seconds.. I have tried to search for a specific row using the same query and adding Where clause at the end, it takes 0.05 sec
What am I missing here ?

Attached Explain
[image]

Comment: Please add the query plan

Comment: Use `EXPLAIN` https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/explain.html to find the execution plan, you are probably missing an index or 2.

Comment: @JanR updated with Explain..

Comment: add indexes for each table on the column used in the joins: i.vin, e.vin and im.vin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like I was missing unique in the other 2 tables, setting vin as unique for all tables and not only the first fixed the problem

Comment: A good lesson. Attempting joins on unindexed columns redults in table scans and poor performance.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add index on table.

```
CREATE INDEX index_name ON Table1 (ID);
```

Answer (score -3):

can you please try using where clause like: 
select tab1.*, tab2.c1,tab2.c2,tab3.c4,tab3.c5 from table1 tab1, table2 tab2, table3 tab3 where tab1.id=tab2.id and tab1.id=tab3.id .
Is this type of query will be helpful to you.
Try to add index on table.

Comment: using antique & non-ansi standard join syntax will not magically fix performance issues.